# How to expand on mouse click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

http://findaccountingsoftware.com/directory/gba-systems/fams-fixed-assets-management-system/
this site contain a tab container. On **Applications** tab clicking on <kbd>+</kbd> sign it goes to expand, I want to know this process name. **How to do it?**. There is a strange thing occur clicking on <kbd>+</kbd> sign expand  automatically scroll move and focus on text. What this process name is. **How to do that?**

Answer (score 1):

This effect is called an 'accordion' menu. jQuery UI has a great one which you can use and also has some great documentation explaining how to use it :)

http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/

Answer (score -1):

Beautiful full customization accordion in Bootstrap.

Please refer the following documentation.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/accordion/

Comment: Question relates to jQuery, not Bootstrap. While it is a fine alternative, it does not pertain to the question at hand